# What is the difference between IIS &Aspnet Containers?

Tags: asp.net, docker, containers, azure-aks

I want to containerize my ASP.Net Framework 4.6 application and I see the following base Images

1. aspnet:4.8-20191210-windowsservercore-ltsc201
2. iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019

What is the difference between those? which is the one to be used to containerize the ASP.Net Framework 4.6 application

Comment: See these official docs :  https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet/ and https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis  The IIS image have IIS only but the aspnet image have multiple dotnet framework versions with IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in these [two](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/blob/master/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile) [docker](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/44da47b0f4e6b0b30a1e3c033b212593c1a6618a/src/aspnet/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile) files, the main difference is the availaibility of `dotnet` framework. `aspnet` image has the framework installed while `iis` one doesn't. You should use `aspnet` base container so that you wouldn't have to install the framework in the container yourself.

Some helpful links:

- [What OS to target with .NET containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/net-container-os-targets)
- [Migrating ASP.NET MVC Applications to Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc)
- [Modernizing Traditional .NET Apps with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/containers-modernizing-traditional-net-apps-with-docker)